# PHP: String to multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, regex

(Sorry for my bad English)

I have a string that I want to split into an array. 
The corner brackets are multiple nested arrays. 
Escaped characters should be preserved.

This is a sample string:

```
$string = '[[["Hello, \"how\" are you?","Good!",,,123]],,"ok"]'
```

The result structure should look like this:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      0 => 'Hello, \"how\" are you?',
      1 => 'Good!',
      2 => '',
      3 => '',
      4 => '123',
    ),
  ),
  1 => '',
  2 => 'ok',
)
```

I have tested it with:

```
$pattern = '/[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*/s';
$return = preg_match_all($pattern, $string, null);
```

But this did not work properly. I do not understand these RegEx patterns (I found this in another example on this page).
I do not know whether preg_match_all is the correct command.

I hope someone can help me.

Many Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to use a lexer in combination with a recursive function that actually builds the structure.

For your purpose, the following tokens have been used:

```
\[           # opening bracket
\]           # closing bracket
".+?(?<!\\)" # " to ", making sure it's not escaped
,(?!,)       # a comma, not followed by a comma
\d+          # at least one digit
,(?=,)       # a comma followed by a comma
```

The rest is programming logic, see a [**demo on ideone.com**](http://ideone.com/tiskwt). Inspired [**by this post**](http://nitschinger.at/Writing-a-simple-lexer-in-PHP/).

---

```
class Lexer {
    protected static $_terminals = array(
        '~^(\[)~'               => "T_OPEN",
        '~^(\])~'               => "T_CLOSE",
        '~^(".+?(?<!\\\\)")~'   => "T_ITEM",
        '~^(,)(?!,)~'           => "T_SEPARATOR",
        '~^(\d+)~'              => "T_NUMBER",
        '~^(,)(?=,)~'           => "T_EMPTY"
    );

    public static function run($line) {
        $tokens = array();
        $offset = 0;
        while($offset < strlen($line)) {
            $result = static::_match($line, $offset);
            if($result === false) {
                throw new Exception("Unable to parse line " . ($line+1) . ".");
            }
            $tokens[] = $result;
            $offset += strlen($result['match']);
        }
        return static::_generate($tokens);
    }

    protected static function _match($line, $offset) {
        $string = substr($line, $offset);

        foreach(static::$_terminals as $pattern => $name) {
            if(preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches)) {
                return array(
                    'match' => $matches[1],
                    'token' => $name
                );
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    // a recursive function to actually build the structure
    protected static function _generate($arr=array(), $idx=0) {
        $output = array();
        $current = 0;
        for($i=$idx;$i<count($arr);$i++) {
            $type = $arr[$i]["token"];
            $element = $arr[$i]["match"];
            switch ($type) {
                case 'T_OPEN':
                    list($out, $index) = static::_generate($arr, $i+1);
                    $output[] = $out;
                    $i = $index;
                    break;
                case 'T_CLOSE':
                    return array($output, $i);
                    break;
                case 'T_ITEM':
                case 'T_NUMBER':
                    $output[] = $element;
                    break;
                case 'T_EMPTY':
                    $output[] = "";
                    break;
            }
        }
        return $output;
    }    
}

$input  = '[[["Hello, \"how\" are you?","Good!",,,123]],,"ok"]';
$items = Lexer::run($input);
print_r($items);

?>
```

Comment: @Then consider upvoting / accepting the answer (green tick on the left).

Answer (score 2):

This is a tough one for a regex - but there is a hack answer to your question (apologies in advance).

The string is almost a valid array literal but for the `,,`s. You can match those pairs and then convert to `,''`s with

`/,(?=,)/`

Then you can `eval` that string into the output array you are looking for.

For example:

```
// input 
$str1 = '[[["Hello, \\"how\\" are you?","Good!",,,123]],,"ok"]';

// replace , followed by , with ,'' with a regex
$pattern = '/,(?=,)/';
$replace = ",''";
$str2 = preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $str1);

// eval updated string
$arr = eval("return $str2;");
var_dump($arr);
```

I get this:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(5) {
      [0]=>
      string(21) "Hello, "how" are you?"
      [1]=>
      string(5) "Good!"
      [2]=>
      string(0) ""
      [3]=>
      string(0) ""
      [4]=>
      int(123)
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  string(0) ""
  [2]=>
  string(2) "ok"
}
```

### Edit

Noting the inherent dangers of `eval` the better option is to use `json_decode` with the code above e.g.:

```
// input 
$str1 = '[[["Hello, \\"how\\" are you?","Good!",,,123]],,"ok"]';

// replace , followed by , with ,'' with a regex
$pattern = '/,(?=,)/';
$replace = ',""';
$str2 = preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $str1);

// eval updated string
$arr = json_decode($str2);
var_dump($arr);
```

Comment: Using eval is a dangerous way since you don't know what contains the string. Replacing `,(?=,)` with `,''` doesn't handle cases when `,,` is between quotes. I'm afraid that the only way to do that is to parse the string character by character or to try to transform it to a well know format like JSON. But it isn't an easy task, not impossible however.

Comment: You are correct - I already apologised for the hack answer in the question.  I believe the same challenge exists for `json_encode` with the `,,` issue.

Comment: Sorry - `json_decode` - this will work if the `,,` is replaced with `""` e.g `var_dump(json_decode('[[["Hello, \"how\" are you?","Good!","","",123]],"","ok"]'));`

Comment: You can solve the `,,` issue using: `$string = preg_replace('~"[^"\\\\]*+(?s:\\\\.[^"\\\\]*)*+"?(*SKIP)(*F)|,\K(?=[],])|\[\K(?=,)~', '""',$string);` *(that handles also cases like `[,` or `,]` and avoids quoted strings.)*

Answer (score 1):

If you can edit the code that serializes the data then it's a better idea to let the serialization be handled using json_encode & json_decode. No need to reinvent the wheel on this one.

Nice cat btw.